# How to configure TeamCity to clone from Gerrit?

Tags: git, teamcity, gerrit

I am configuring TeamCity integration with Gerrit Code-Review. I set up a TeamCity project and added a VCS Root. The TeamCity user is added to Gerrit along with its SSH key (this part works, cloning from the command line with `git clone ssh://` works).

In the VCS Root configuration, I set the Fetch URL to `ssh://teamcity@gerrit.local:29418/MyProject` but then I test the connection I am getting this error:

```
Test connection failed in MyProject :: MyProject-gerrit.
Cannot find revision of the default branch 'refs/for/dev' of vcs root
"jetbrains.git" {instance id=28, parent internal id=-1,
parent id=dummy_jetbrains.git,
description: "ssh://teamcity@gerrit.local:29418/MyProject#refs/for/dev"}
```

The URL TeamCity is attempting to fetch is indeed wrong, if I try to clone from that with `git` in the CLI, it appears that the project name is `MyProject%23refs/for/dev`.

What is the correct way to configure TeamCity to work with Gerrit's repository?

Comment: How do you notify teamcity, the poll mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by not setting any default branch in the VCS settings, and setting `+:refs/changes/*` and `+:refs/heads/*` as branch specification.